# How do I calculate the electrical charge that is applied on metal layer?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

[image]

In the sketched arrangement, there are two weakly conductive dielectric disks between two circular metal electrodes $M_1$ and $M_2$, and a metal layer S between them. The whole arrangement is traversed by a direct current of the strength $I = 10 mA$.

$\epsilon_{r1}=2, \gamma_1=3 \cdot 10^{-4} S/m$

$\epsilon_{r2}=5, \gamma_2=4 \cdot 10^{-4} S/m$

Calculate the electrical charge that is applied to layer S.

Comment: This is not a homework answering service so what are your ideas about how to solve this problem?

Comment: I know that isn't. So I know that Q=C*Q, than C=Epsilon*A/l, I have current, I can calculate how much is J, than I know that gamma*E is J, I find E, I put that with integral and than I calculate U and than I substract two charges? @Farcher

Answer (score 0):

Why not find the resistance of the slabs of dielectric knowing the conductivity of the dielectrics?
Use the definition of resistance, $V=IR$, to find the potential differences across each of the slabs of dielectric.
Use the parallel plate capacitance equation to find the charge stored on each capacitor.
Draw a diagram to show how the positive and negative charges are distributed and use it to find the net charge on the metal plate.

Comment: But the formula for resistance $\frac{l}{\gamma A}$ I'm not sure what exactly is area and thickness here, I would say that area is for the first one is 1x20mm^2 but, what is than my l here?

Comment: The diameter (so you can find the area $A$) & thickness $t$ of the dielectrics are given so use the defining equation for conductance $\gamma$, which is $R=\frac{t}{\gamma A}$, to find the resistance.

Comment: I know, but what is value of thickness in my example? @farcher

Comment: In the diagram it says 1 mm and 4 mm.

Comment: And the are of first is for example 1mmx200mm? Right?

Comment: You are looking at a side view and the area is the area of a disc of diameter 20 mm.

Comment: So that will be $\pi*100mm^2$ ?